# overflow-x moving text up

Tags: html, css

I'm making a file manager, and it's supposed to display some details about the file when a file is selected. However, the text is moved up a bit, so it looks out of line.[image]

**HTML**

```
<img src='folder.png' width='60' style='float: left;vertical-align: top;margin-right: 8px;'>";
<span class='text-muted'>Name:</span> 
<span style='display: inline-block; min-width: 100px;max-width: 120px; overflow-x: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;'>codeflask</span>
<span class='text-muted'>Size:</span> 
<span style='display: inline-block; min-width: 100px;max-width: 120px; overflow-x: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;'>4 KB</span>
<br>
<span class='text-muted'>Type:</span> 
<span style='display: inline-block; min-width: 100px;max-width: 120px; overflow-x: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;'>directory</span>
```

When I removed the `overflow-x: hidden;` part, it looked fine. However, the text overflows, and I want it to stop with the ellipsis when it gets too long.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried overflow-x: auto?  That way it will only overflow (with a scroll) if necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add this CSS

```
span { vertical-align: baseline; }
```

to get all of them (which are in a line) on the same vertical position.

(If you also have other spans, you need to use either a class that you give them all or use a wrapper element in the HTML and a combined selector like

```
#my_wrapper span { vertical-align: baseline; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was you were using `inline-block` elements (property values) following `inline` elements (property names). They can be aligned using `inline-block` display with `vertical-align` set to same value. I rewrote it a little - and also, removed inline CSS and created classes:

```css
span {
  font-family: sans-serif
}
.property-name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 4em;
  text-align: right;
}
.property-value {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 120px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.file-thumb {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<img src='folder.png' width='60' class='file-thumb'>
<span class='property-name'>Name:</span> 
<span class='property-value'>codeflask</span>
<span class='property-name'>Size:</span> 
<span class='property-value'>4 KB</span>
<br>
<span class='property-name'>Type:</span> 
<span class='property-value'>directory</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `white-space: nowrap;`